# How to reverse two dimensional java array?

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I am writing java code for a music demo in which
I have a java array:

```
int[][] a = {{1,2,3,},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12};
```

and I want to reverse this array to get this shape:

```
int[][] b = {{3,2,1},{6,5,4},{9,8,7},{12,11,10}};
```

Kindly suggest me some easy solution for it.

Comment: You're hardly "reversing a two dimensional array". It's more like reversing each 1D array contained in a 2D array.

Comment: How would you solve this if you were doing it by hand? It is much easier to reason about these sorts of things if you work out a few small examples on a whiteboard or paper.

Comment: Does going through all arrays in a loop and reversing them sounds easy enough?..

Comment: You have to show what you have tried, we will attempt to help you, but will not just give you a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use Collections.reverse(), here's how to do it manually:

```
    int[][] a = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}};
    int[][] ar = new int[a.length][];
    int len, index;
    for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        len = a[i].length;
        ar[i] = new int[len];
        index = len-1;
        for (int j=0; j < len; j++) {
            ar[i][j] = a[i][index];
            index--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ar));
```

Comment: You have given a nice solution, it really worked and the problem is over.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Collections.reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) to reverse the order of elements in a list. As you need to reverse each array in your outer-array, you'll need to iterate over the inner arrays with a for loop.

*Note*: For this, you need to use an ArrayList instead of arrays. You can transform an array to an ArrayList by using `Arrays.asList(array)`.

In practice:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(a); //Where a is your original array
for (List<Integer> sublist : list)
  Collections.reverse(sublist);
```

Now list contains your reversed sublists.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Ad Fundum's answer if you really need to use `double[][]` as a type, try this:

```
double[] reverse(double[] a)
{
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(a); //Where a is your original array
for (List<Integer> sublist : list)
  Collections.reverse(sublist);
return list.toArray(new Double[a.length]);
}

for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
   b[i] = reverse(a[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[][] a = {{1,2,3,},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}};
int[][] b = new int[a.length][];

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
        b[i][j] = a[i][a[i].length - (j + 1)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this code I am facing the probem of java.lang.NullPointerException. How it can be resolved?

Comment: I missed one line before second for iteration: b[i] = new int[a[i].length];